# While accessing mongo db through java driver, does a socket timeout on read close the connection as well?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongo, mongo-java-driver

I'm accessing mongo db (v2.6) through java driver (v2.10) (through spring data). When the application receive a socket timeout exception, is the underlying connection closed as well?

Answer (score 0):

The connection is getting closed, but spring automatically establishes a new connection. So u need not create a new connection.